# TCP send a file data from client to server problem: different checksum on file

Tags: c, file, sockets, tcp

I try to transfer a data size of around 100MB over a TCP ipv4 connection socket.

I calculate the CheckSum in the client before sending it to see what the checksum is.

After sending the data file to the server and the server writes it to a new file I calculate again the checksum and I can see a differents.

I think is probably with my send and receive functions.

The Sender function used in CLIENT :

```
void send_file(FILE *fp, int sockfd) {
    int n;
    char data[SIZE] = {0};

    while (fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1) {
            perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
            exit(1);
        }
        bzero(data, SIZE);
    }
}
```

The Writer function the use in the SERVER:

```
    void write_file(int sockfd, char *filename) {
    int n;
    FILE *fp;
    //char *filename = "new_data.txt";
    char buffer[SIZE];

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    while (1) {
        n = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0);
        if (n <= 0) {
            break;
            return;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
        bzero(buffer, SIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using fread() and fwrite() instead of fgets() and fprintf(). And check the result of fread(), it tells you how many bytes you read, so you should only send that many bytes.

Comment: There's good advice below. But you likely need to invoke `fopen` with `"rb"` and `"wb"` on Windows so that `\r\n` doesn't get translated in the text stream.

Comment: The bzero() call is a cargo-cult waste of cycles and, anyway, is in the wtong place to zero the buffer first-time-through.  You don"t need to treat the buffer cintent as a NUL-terminated string because you know 'n'.  I have seen this code multiple times, all with the same issues. Copy your code from a better source.

Comment: _Side note:_ Too bad you deleted your question on pipes being too slow. As a consequence, this is the only way to reach you. 2 hours isn't an inordinately long time to leave a question up. I just finished an answer. My solution took 0.1 secs for 100MB at a rate of 653 MB/s. You could "undelete" your question if you still need help [or ask a new one and reply to me here to alert me]

Comment: @CraigEstey I am so  Sorry, I thought it was no relevant anymore if you can help me I will  be appreciated it and learn from that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74746348/pipe-with-file-fread-fwrite-send-file-from-one-process-to-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgets() and fprintf() are used for reading and writing zero-terminated strings, not arbitrary binary data. fread() and fwrite() are your friends here. Something like:

Client:

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 1024
char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];

while ((num_bytes = fread(buffer, 1, CHUNK_SIZE, fp)) > 0)
{
    send(sockfd, buffer, num_bytes, 0);
}
```

Server:

```
// Same chunk size and buffer as above

while ((num_bytes = recv(sock, buffer, CHUNK_SIZE, 0)) > 0)
{
    fwrite(buffer, 1, num_bytes, fp);
}
```

Technically fwrite() and send() can write less bytes than you ask them to, and you really should loop until all bytes are written.

You should also technically open your files with modes "rb" and "wb" for binary files.

Comment: Windows needs the `"b"` mode passed as well.  i.e. `"rb"` and `"wb"` in the `fopen` call.

Comment: @pmacfarlane i change to your code and I change the fopens to rb and wb and still different checksum but the file looks equals I don't know what the problem

Comment: Do the file sizes match? How are you doing the checksum? In code, or using an external tool like sha256sum or md5sum?

Comment: I use a function that calculates the checksum of the file, the files look equal to the same size and the same bytes size like 100% equal but maybe some of the chars are missing I don't know really, or the checksum function is wrong.

Comment: What OS are you using? If Linux, please run md5sum and/or sha256sum on both files and see if they match. If they do, there is a bug in your function. Which would be a separate question :-D.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I running on windows WSL Ubuntu 22.04  I can edit this post and add the checksum function

Comment: You should almost certainly have sha256sum and md5sum in WSL. If nothing else you should have a program called "cksum". Try it and see. I think your checksum code is a new question.

Comment: @pmacfarlane https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709938/difference-in-checksum-in-tcp-udp-sockets-server-client