# pipe with file fread & fwrite send file from one process to another

Tags: c, file, pipe, fork

I Implement a pipe that "transfers" from one process data file size of 100MB to another process.

The Whole Send from one process to the another works well, but it takes soo long... around 2.5+ minutes.

I want to change my functions to fread&fwrite to make the function faster instead reading one char each time how I can do it with the pd[0] & pd[1] but I hardly understand how I can change it

Any help will be appreciated!

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pid_t childpid;
    char readbuffer[65535];

    pipe(fd);

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (childpid == 0) {
        /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd[0]);

        /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
        FILE *fp2 = fopen("data.txt", "rb");

        if (fp2 == NULL) {
            //handle error here
            return -1;
        }
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(fp2)) != EOF) {
            if ((write(fd[1], &c, 1)) < 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Write to pipe failed.\n");
                perror("write");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    } else {
        /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd[1]);

        /* Read in a string from the pipe */
        char *new_data = "new_data.txt";
        FILE *fp = fopen(new_data, "wb");
        ssize_t num_bytes;
        while (num_bytes = (read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer))) > 0) {
            fwrite(readbuffer, 1, num_bytes, fp);
            memset(readbuffer, 0, 65535);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDITED ROUND 2:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pid_t childpid;
    char readbuffer[1024];

    pipe(fd);

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (childpid == 0) {
        /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd[0]);

        /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
        FILE *fp2 = fopen("data.txt", "rb");

        if (fp2 == NULL) {
            //handle error here
            return -1;
        }
        int c;
//        while ((c = getc(fp2)) != EOF) {
//            if ((write(fd[1], &c, 1)) < 1) {
//                fprintf(stderr, "Write to pipe failed.\n");
//                perror("write");
//                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//            }
//        }
        ssize_t num_bytes;
        while ((num_bytes = fread(readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer), 1024,fp2)) > 0) {
            fwrite(readbuffer, 1, num_bytes, fd[1]);
            //memset(readbuffer, 0, 65535);
        }
    } else {
        /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd[1]);

        /* Read in a string from the pipe */
        char *new_data = "new_data.txt";
        FILE *fp = fopen(new_data, "wb");
        ssize_t num_bytes;
        while ((num_bytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer))) > 0) {
            fwrite(readbuffer, 1, num_bytes, fp);
            //memset(readbuffer, 0, 65535);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: It' meaningless to clear out the read buffer if it will get overwritten afterwards anyway – all this *effectively* does is consuming some CPU runtime.

Comment: `while (num_bytes = (read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer))) > 0)` The parentheses are placed wrong.

Comment: You should not need the `memset` call.

Comment: And don't use large buffers when dealing with pipes, the pipe will itself have rather small buffers. Larger than `1024` don't always help.

Comment: You're reading and writing on the receiver side in chunks already – doing so on the sender side is analogous, just use `fread` instead of `read` and `write` instead of `fwrite`...

Comment: Also, why do you read byte by bytes from the input file, and write byte by byte to the pipe Why not read and write blocks instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i deleted the memset, i did change to 1024  size, i need help in how i can not read byte by bytes its what i ask for help, i edit the parentheses to be right placed

Comment: @ATB You actually already know how to (you just don't know that you know...) – you did so on receiver/parent side, just with file and pipe swapped. It's exactly analogous on sender/child.

Comment: You know about [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite), so I would assume you also know about [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread)? Use `fread` to read into a buffer, then `write` that buffer to the pipe. Match the buffer sizes in both processes.

Comment: Don't use `read` or `write` at all.  Use `fdopen` to get `FILE *` s and use `getc` and `putc`. All of the optimizations for buffer sizes will be handled for you by the library.

Comment: One can use `read` and `write` _or_ `fread` and `fwrite`, but should certainly never mix buffered and unbuffered I/O.

Comment: @ATB, ...why are did you choose `getc` instead of `fread` in the first place?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i EDITED TO ROUND 2 i got some errors,

Comment: **`fread`** not `read`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got error in the fwrite i think i did worng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues ...

In your original code, the main issue [speed wise] was using `read` or `write` with a length of 1.

Also, although a stream may compensate a bit for `fgetc`, it is  still one byte at a time.

The solution I've come up with is to implement what William Pursell suggested: Use `fdopen` to attach a stdio stream (i.e. `FILE *`) to the pipe.

We can do this for both parent and child.

Then, just looping on `fread/fwrite` in both processes works.

Note that the parent and should do `fclose`.

And, the parent should wait for the child to complete (e.g. `waitpid`).

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        int sverr = errno; \
        fprintf(stderr,_fmt); \
        errno = sverr; \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

int
main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    FILE *fpinp;
    FILE *fpout;
    pid_t childpid;
    int status;
    ssize_t rlen;
    ssize_t wlen;
#if 0
    char buffer[65535];
#else
    char buffer[1024];
#endif

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    setlinebuf(stderr);

    pipe(fd);

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (childpid == 0) {
        /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd[0]);

        /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
        fpinp = fopen("data.txt", "rb");
        if (fpinp == NULL) {
            perror("child/fopen");
            exit(7);
        }

        fpout = fdopen(fd[1],"wb");
        if (fpout == NULL) {
            perror("child/fdopen");
            exit(8);
        }

        while (1) {
            rlen = fread(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),fpinp);
            dbgprt("child: LOOP rlen=%zd\n",rlen);

            if (rlen < 0) {
                perror("child/fread");
                exit(9);
            }

            if (rlen <= 0)
                break;

            wlen = fwrite(buffer,1,rlen,fpout);
            dbgprt("child: LOOP wlen=%zd\n",wlen);

            if (wlen < 0) {
                perror("child/fwrite");
                exit(9);
            }
        }

        fclose(fpinp);
        fclose(fpout);

        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd[1]);

        /* Read in a string from the pipe */
        char *new_data = "new_data.txt";
        fpout = fopen(new_data, "wb");
        if (fpout == NULL) {
            perror("parent/fopen");
            exit(3);
        }

        fpinp = fdopen(fd[0],"rb");
        if (fpinp == NULL) {
            perror("parent/fdopen");
            exit(4);
        }

        while (1) {
            rlen = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fpinp);
            dbgprt("parent: LOOP rlen=%zd\n",rlen);
            if (rlen < 0) {
                perror("parent/fread");
                exit(5);
            }
            if (rlen <= 0)
                break;

            wlen = fwrite(buffer, 1, rlen, fpout);
            dbgprt("parent: LOOP wlen=%zd\n",wlen);
            if (wlen < 0) {
                perror("parent/fwrite");
                exit(6);
            }
        }

        fclose(fpinp);
        fclose(fpout);

        waitpid(childpid,&status,0);
        dbgprt("status=%8.8X\n",status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works Like Magic, Thanks. Little Complected but amazing.

Comment: @ATB _"Just because we can’t find a solution it doesn’t mean that there isn’t one."_ Words to live by, don't you think? ;-)